# Grub does not load on boot after transfer of SSD drive to another laptop

Tags: linux, ssd, grub, lvm, luks

I got two laptops of the same make and model, laptop Alpha and laptop Beta. Alpha runs a LUKS encrypted LVM of linux and is partitioned into three parts: Grub, swap, and the encrypted drive. It's been running great for about 4 years.

The problem is I use Alpha so much that it's always on, and it's always pushed to its limits (lots of tabs open in browser, lots of apps running at once). Well, eventually it must have been so hot that the glue melted on the lid and eventually the hinges and the screen started coming apart. It's now to the point that, while it's still usable, it cannot be moved or it'll fall apart and get damaged further. So I decided to simply remove the SSD card and put it into the Beta laptop. They're both the same make and model, so it should be fine, right?

Wrong.

The problem is that now when I turn Beta on I get a menu to either select a drive or enter BIOS. The drive selection just says "Kingston" (that's the SSD) and "Windows" (there is no Windows drive). Grub is not recognized at all. And if I try hitting enter on either of the drive options nothing happens. Even when I enter BIOS I don't see Grub listed, I still only see Kingston and Windows as boot drive options. I made sure the BIOS was set up exactly the same way as Alpha but that doesn't change anything.

So I used Kali Live USB to boot and see if at least I could access my data. Sure enough, all my data is there. All three of the partitions are still intact on the SSD. But since this is a live boot I have to set things up every time I reboot, which means I need to keep the computer on all the time. I managed to write a shell script to do a lot of the setup (apt update and what not) but that takes a few minutes to load, and I really just want to turn on my computer and get what I had before, a Grub loader to boot into my encrypted drive and load my OS with all my preferences.

How do I fix this? What further troubleshooting can I do?

Any help is much appreciate!

Comment: Try to fix Grub by using the [Super Grub Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Comment: Are the UEFI (or BIOS if really old) settings the same? You need to match the mode it was originally installed: Preferably you should've installed in UEFI mode and then the 2nd laptop should be set as well to UEFI mode. However, you don't mention any ESP. Or is it what you call "Grub" partition? If you installed in Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode the 2nd must as well have CSM enabled, if not CSM only. Another hypotheses: Was there any other drive in the 1st and the ESP resides there perhaps? That being the case it won't work by simply transferring the drive to the 2nd.